# Magento 2 GraphQL on family tree

Tags: magento2, graphql

I have a tree that includes the following information:

```
tree {
   id: Int
   parent: tree
   children: [tree]
}
```

How to write graphQL module that can handle the following query:

```
{
  tree (
  id: 4
) {
  children {
    id
    parent {
      id
      children {
        id
      }
    }
  }
}
}
```

and can the query repeat infinitely like that?
The result could be:

```
{
  "data": {
    "tree": [
      {
        "id": 4,
        "children": [
          {
            "id": "5",
            "parent": {
                "id": 4
                "children": [
                   {
                       "id": 5
                    }
                ]
            }
           }
        ]
      }
    }
}
```